# Display an asp page in word to print it with interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I have an asp.net page with connection to database, that inserts, edits, and updates. It is in asp.net and c#. It contains textboxes ,labels and diaries.

What I am trying to do: make this page be displayed in Word with a button, in order to print it, with all fields after i fill them, like doing a "print screen" and print with each function.
I have already installed INTEROP, but i have not found any tutorial for "make an asp page with database appear on word"

Sequence of events:
-Fill all the fields.
-Export webpage to Microsoft Word, with all the filled fields.
-Print all filled fields.

Is this possible? How should i start?

Comment: Even if you don't know how to do it, can you describe your expected flow here? Like, what's the sequence of events that should happen?

Comment: If you have it working in Excel.. then the rest can be done with this. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b9efd8e0-7c5f-4191-a878-c39d355bf043/render-excel-document-to-word-document-using-cnet?forum=exceldev

Comment: You could look for libraries that help you create docx files, or you could generate a PDF.